# How to use Admob AdView contructor without an Activity?

Tags: android, constructor, admob

I have tried to create an AdView instance without an existing Activity:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html

**AdView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)** // Construct an AdView from an XML layout.

```
XmlPullParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.admob);
AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
adView = new AdView(context, attributes);
```

I have tried different kind of XML contents but I cannot really find a proper solution.

One example of the XML that I have tried:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:id="@+id/my_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ads:adSize="BANNER">
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

No matter I try, the following exception is thrown:

```
LogCat: E/AndroidRuntime(29853): Caused by: com.google.ads.internal.b: Required XML attribute "adSize" missing
E/AndroidRuntime(29853):    at com.google.ads.AdView.b(SourceFile:467)
E/AndroidRuntime(29853):    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:336)
```

Can somebody show me an example how to use this variation of the AdView constructor?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you going to do with an ad if not display it in an Activity?

Comment: There are some rare cases when there is only a view with no activity. Such as overlay views made by a service. Later I realized that the constructor is probably used by the Android itself, since also the base class has a similar constructor.

Comment: Stange too that the older AdMob API has a constructor with only Context parameter. Why it has been changed to an Activity type.. And why I cannot even find an up-to-date API reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out that it was either not possible or too difficult to construct an AdView without an Activity.

But as a solution for "how to create an AdView for an environment with no Activity", it was not that difficult after all.

Just do the following:

- Start a dummy Activity to create an AdView. Close the Activity immediatelly with finish().
- Detach the AdView from the Activity view hierarchy and add it to any place you might need it.

Seems to work fine (Android 4.2, at least).

Comment: Could you please provide a running example ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting

```
Required XML attribute "adSize" missing
```

is because you do not have an `adSize` attribute in the XML config for your AdView. You need to choose what size ad to display.

See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear. I can create the AdView with Activity when I can specify the AdView in layout (with adSize attribute). Similar kind of approach does not seem to be trivial to implement with this specific constructor; only AttributeSet it provided. And yes, I tried to specify adSize in all possible ways, but it always fails for the same reason.

Comment: I even tried to make an own implementation for the AttributeSet to make sure all attributes are provided. But it crash for class cast exception. So my assumption was that only Xml attribute set is supported.

Comment: Edited the question. One example of the XML has been added. The most obvious format is to use a similar kind of content than in activity layout XML.

Comment: Reviewing your use case I don't believe it is possible to show a View from a Service without first creating an Activity. I don't think you are going to get this to work.

Comment: No, I'm certain it's possible to create and show a view from service without any Activity. But anyway, I'm convinced the AdView cannot be instantiated without an Activity.

Comment: I'd love to see a ref to an example that does that. A Service has no Window in which to display a View. You can start an Activity from a Service, but you can't show anything directly.

Comment: You can try it yourself. Create a view with TOAST or similar type. Then add it to the view manager. Nothing too tricky. The use cases are relatively limited, such as alert popups.

Comment: I think you are on your own here. The Android frameowkr was designed such that views are provided via Activities. Sefvices are not expected to have any view content. The fact that you happen to be able to find a corner case where some of this might work doesn't mean that it is a good path to tread. I'd strongly suggest you revisit your use case.